# Selecting Part of String inside an Input Box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to highlight just some part of text inside an input box using jQuery. It's quite simple to highlight the entire contents of the input box but how do you highlight just one word or couple of letters?

Thanks!

Comment: By "select", do you mean mark it as selected? Blue, with white text?

Comment: What do you mean by _select_? Do you mean highlight like what happens when you select with your cursor?

Comment: I fixed the wording. I used the word select but what I really meant was highlight. I apologize for the mistake.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For text `<input>` elements, the following will do the job. The example selects just the word "two" in the input:

```js
function setInputSelection(input, startPos, endPos) {
    input.focus();
    if (typeof input.selectionStart != "undefined") {
        input.selectionStart = startPos;
        input.selectionEnd = endPos;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE branch
        input.select();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd("character", endPos);
        range.moveStart("character", startPos);
        range.select();
    }
}

document.getElementById("setSelection").onmousedown = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("i");
    setInputSelection(input, 4, 7);
    return false;
};
```

```html
<input id="i" type="text" value="One two three">
<input type="button" value="Set selection" id="setSelection">
```

Comment: Honestly, I know this is not an educational comment, but come on IE, really!! 7 lines of code versus 2. Sure your way may add more functionality to the mix, but unnecessary. Thank you Tim for providing this example!

Comment: @JasonFoglia: The code for doing this reliably in old IE in textareas, where there could be empty lines, is [much bigger still](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373056/96100). In fairness, IE 9 fixes this by supporting `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

Comment: I know this is old but Firefox requires this `input.focus();` before `input.selectionStart = startPos;`

Comment: @BojanDević: Since textareas can have selections while not focussed in some browsers, I tend to try and keep the two things separate, but I think I agree with you for this question.

Comment: Looks like fiddle do not works in latest Firefox (44.0.2)

Comment: @vatavale: The main code will work fine for many years to come but the jsFiddle has issues with focus. I've changed it to use a code snippet instead and added a button to set the selection.

Answer (score -3):

You will need to select the entire value, and then manipulate the string in code. Depending on what you're trying to do with the words, you might look in to using regular expressions to match certain words/letters.

Comment: How does your code highlight a portion of text inside of a input textbox?