# Selecting a part of the contents of an input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

It's a bit moot point but I'm still curious why the two following lines aren't equivalent.

```
$("#boink").selectionStart = 3;
document.getElementById("boink").selectionStart = 3;
```

The working example comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085446/selecting-part-of-string-inside-an-input-box-with-jquery). For some reason, the jQuery fetched control doesn't have the property *selectionStart* nor *selectionEnd*.

What should be used instead if I'm still going to apply jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#boink")` will return jQuery object and not the control itself. To get the control you have to take element with `.get` method or using `[]` notation:

```
$("#boink")[0].selectionStart = 3;
$("#boink").get(0).selectionStart = 3;
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because `$("#boink")` is a jQuery object and not the DOM element itself. In order to make those 2 lines equivalente you should do

```
$("#boink")[0].selectionStart = 3;
```

The array contains all matched DOM elements. Since you're selecting by id, one element can match as most so you just pick the first one using `[0]`

Comment: Oh, right. I assumed that when we go by id using #-sign, there's no need to specify the first element in the array. My bad...

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the original DOM element using

```
$("#boink")[0].selectionStart = 3;
```