# How to .select() part of an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an input to search ids, you can type one or more letters and the first id who starts by that letter/letters will be filled inside the input, but as you can see, it's still not intuitive:

Type **a** or **ab** to test the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(Hi);
function Hi(){
        var keys = "";
        $("input").keyup(function(e){
                var inp = $(this);
                var wk = event.which;
                if(wk!=8){                                               //if not pressed backspace
                        if((wk >= 65 && wk <= 120) && (wk != 32 && wk != 0)){  //allow just letters
                            keys = keys+ e.key;
                        }
                        inp.val($("p[id^="+keys+"]").attr("id"))
                        //inp.val(inp.val().slice(keys.length));  //this is just the
                        //inp.val(keys+(inp.val().select()));     //idea, but wont work
                }else{
                        inp.val("");
                        keys="";
                }
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>

<p id="apple"></p>
<p id="abocado"></p>
<p id="abanico"></p>
```

The idea is to view just the typed letter/letters normally, and select the rest of the word to let the user knows he can keep typing after his typed text and not after the entire word who was filled in by the program.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to make this work? I'm accepting css too.

**EDIT**

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085446/selecting-part-of-string-inside-an-input-box-with-jquery), I've made this work:

```js
$(document).ready(Hi);
function Hi(){
        var keys = "";
        $("input").keyup(function(e){
                var inp = $(this);
                var wk = event.which;
                if(wk!=8){
                        if((wk >= 65 && wk <= 120) && (wk != 32 && wk != 0)) { 
                            keys = keys+ e.key;
                        }
                        var par = $("p[id^="+keys+"]").attr("id");
                        inp.val(par)
                        letSelect(inp[0],keys.length,par.length);
                }else{
                        inp.val("");
                        keys="";
                }
        });
}

function letSelect(input, startPos, endPos) {
    input.focus();
    if (typeof input.selectionStart != "undefined") {
        input.selectionStart = startPos;
        input.selectionEnd = endPos;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        input.select();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd("character", endPos);
        range.moveStart("character", startPos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>

<p id="apple"></p>
<p id="abocado"></p>
<p id="abanico"></p>
```

Comment: If you are talking about being intuitive, highlighting part of an input field does not intuitively tell me anything about what you are trying to convey to me.

Comment: Agreed. For this, I would actually use a list that shows the available options below the input, and then you could select from that list using your keyboard arrow keys or mouse.

Comment: ^ an autocomplete fits this nicely

Comment: Have you tried to search for it in google? Pasted the title in google and first result was the answer

Comment: Maybe it's not the most intuitive and I know how to make this with a list, but I realy need to do this as I've described.

Comment: @MarkE that's curious, first result is just this same question and the next three are w3fools.com.